# Azure WebApp Deployment: Throw expression causes compiler error CS1525

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, c#-7.0

I'm currently using the new throw expression in C# as such:

```
_configurator = configurator ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(configurator));
```

It compiles just fine inside Visual Studio 2017 however when deploying to my staging slot from my version control (in this case BitBucket) it fails with:

```
Repositories\UserRepository.cs(46,45): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'throw' [D:\home\site\repository\foo\foo.csproj]
```

This occurs in several places across my project.

How can I set my WebApp to allow compilation of this new throw feature? The only workaround I found right now is to compile it locally and publish manually through Visual Studio. I would like to use the automated deployment option that Azure allows.

I found this [error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28293/throw-expression-causes-compiler-error-cs1525.html) that relates to a local project but I'm not sure how to upgrade the Microsoft.Net.Compilers on the WebApp. My slot is set to .NET 4.6

Thanks,

Comment: You may also be required to update the MSBuild tools on your server

Comment: @VMAtm Adding `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` per David's answer solved the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a reference to the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` NuGet package in all the projects in the solution. See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2350 for more details on this.

Comment: Added the Nuget package `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` solved the issue. I published the solution once more then all subsequent commits built as expected. Thanks David.

Comment: Great! Eventually we'll add the VS 2017 tooling and this extra step won't be necessary. But for now it's an easy enough workaround.

Comment: @DavidEbbo: Thank you very much, that solved my problem!

Comment: I tried to install the Nuget package Microsoft.Net.Compiles but got a subsequent deployment error: 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers is only supported on MSBuild v15.0 and above'

Comment: Works with Microsoft.Net.Compilers v2.0.1 https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2350#issuecomment-350585074